# Sending an E-Mail issue with the From sender

Tags: c#, winforms, email

I am trying to send the e-mail to the g-mail, it is success, but the from sender is same with the to recipient. Why is it like that? Could you guys help me?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
public static void SendEmail(string _from, string _subject, string _body)
        {
            try
            {
                _message.From = new MailAddress(_from);
                _message.To.Add(new MailAddress("fuhansxavega92@gmail.com"));
                _message.Subject = _subject;
                _message.Body = _body;

                _smtp.Port = 587;
                _smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                _smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                _smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                _smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                _smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                _smtp.Send(_message);

                ShowMessageBox("Your message has been successfully sent", "Success", 2);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowMessageBox("Message : " + ex.Message + string.Empty, "Error", 1);
            }
        }

void contactToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SystemManager.SendEmail("risna22sakura@gmail.com", "Testing", "Testing");
        }
```

And here is the result (as image), I am upload it to the dropbox, because the StackOverflow does not allow me to post an image:

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/raulmbjhq0i3n7c/Capture.PNG?dl=0)

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the `_from` variable is different than your `_to`?

Comment: Yes, because I am passing the value `_from` variable to the `risna22sakura@gmail.com` at `contact...` function, and as for `to`, it is defined at `SendEmail` function sir.

Comment: My guess is you have an additional smtp configuration section (app.config?) and those settings override whatever you write in your code. Do you have smtp settings somewhere in a config-file?

Comment: No, there is no stmp settings somewhere sir, just this one. @DrCopyPaste

Comment: @UnknownUser hum, but that email address showing up in from has to appear somewhere, did you try search all files' contents in your project folder for that string `fuhansxavega92@gmail.com`? Maybe that way you can identify the location where that is being used, seems to be not in the code snippets you included in your question.

Comment: If you solved your own question you should post it as an answer, not change your question. After a day or so you can accept your own answer; that will mark your question as answered in the UI.

Comment: Thank you @DourHighArch. Will remember that for the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void SendEmail(string _fromEmail, string _fromEmailPassword, string _subject, string _body)
        {
            try
            {
                _message.From = new MailAddress(_fromEmail);
                _message.To.Add(new MailAddress("fuhansxavega92@gmail.com"));
                _message.Subject = _subject;
                _message.Body = _body;

                _smtp.Port = 587;
                _smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                _smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                _smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                _smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("_fromEmail", "_fromEmailPassword");
                _smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                _smtp.Send(_message);

                ShowMessageBox("Your message has been successfully sent", "Success", 2);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowMessageBox("Message : " + ex.Message + string.Empty, "Error", 1);
            }
```

I have solved the problem and the above code is the solution to it. My mistake, from the `NetworkCredential`, it should be `from the sender`, not `to the recipient` as well as the `password`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this and check your passing parameter from the _from,

```
//To create MailMessage object
            string strPassword = txtPassword.Text;
        string strEmailAddress = txtFromEmailAddress.Text;
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");//Set SMTP to gmail
            mail.From = new MailAddress(strFromEmailAddress);//From side emailAdress
            mail.To.Add(txtClientAddress.Text);//To side email Address
            mail.Subject = strEmailTitle;//Subject to define
            mail.Body = PreviewEmail();//Appending the body string to the Mail Body
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;//Set attachment object

            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            SmtpServer.Port = 587;


            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strFromEmailAddress, strPassword);
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Still cannot. @LostCoder

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the credentials of risna22sakura@gmail.com ?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you pass `From` and `To` into the constructor like so:

`var mail = new MailMessage("sender@hotmail.com", "recipient@hotmail.com");`

`To` and `From` are read only.

Comment: Err, so how about the `To` and `From`? Once I deleted those two and replace it with your code above. The error message appear and said `The From must be specified`

Comment: You can replace whole 4 lines for setting the `_message` with one conctructor liek this: `var mail = new MailMessage(_from,"fuhansxavega92@gmail.com",_subject,_body)` if afther that still you will get `The from mus be specified` this would be strange for me

Comment: Where did this 'message appear'?